# CSS - Background color to image/video slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I am trying to add background color to the overall image slider located at http://192.241.239.235 so that it looks like

[image: this].

I have tried adding the `style` attribute

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
overflow: auto;
```

to the

```
<div id='content'>
```

but the background color just does not show.

Comment: you need to hide the banner slider, `opacity` seemed to work for me.

Comment: @AdamAzad can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an overlay on your slides that you can change here: `.tp-banner ul li:after`. And I see that you need to give it a higher ´z-index´ to make it appear above the video in the slideshow.

```css
/* The fullscreen video */
.tp-caption.fullscreenvideo {
  z-index: 0;
}

/* The covering black */
.tp-banner ul li:after {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* All slideshow content */
.tp-caption {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested, the background color has been applied but the text on it has also become grey as opposed to white as shown in the image above.
You can check the updated app [here](http://www.veebox.io)

Comment: I updated the code with some comments. `.tp-caption` is both the content inside the slideshow and the video so I just put that in the far back.